# how to fill up the gaps in Rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have mart table where i have gaps in rows.I tried using loop condition but I'm unable to proceed

```
CREATE TABLE Mart
    (martID int, mart int)
;

INSERT INTO Mart
    (martID, mart)
VALUES
    (1, 10),
    (4, 12),
    (6, 20)
;
```

**OutPut**

```
martID       mart
1             10
2             0
3             0
4             12
5             0
6             20
```

My code so far

```
select  max(martId) as nr
        from    Mart
        union all
        select  nr - 1
        from    numbers
        where   nr > 1
```

Comment: What do you  mean by gaps?

Comment: rows missing need to be sequential order by ID's

Comment: You should add primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this works

```
declare @Mart TABLE 
    (martID int, mart int)
;

INSERT INTO @Mart
    (martID, mart)
VALUES
    (1, 10),
    (4, 12),
    (6, 20)
;
declare @MinNo int
declare @MaxNo int
declare @IncrementStep int
set @MinNo = 1
set @MaxNo = 10
set @IncrementStep = 1

;with C as
(
  select @MinNo as Num
  union all 
  select Num + @IncrementStep
  from C 
  where Num < @MaxNo
)      
select Num,
CASE WHEN mart IS NOT NULL THEN mart ELSE 0 END AS NUMBER
from C  
LEFT JOIN @Mart t
ON t.martID = c.Num
```

Comment: when data changes case condition becomes problem @mohan111

Comment: yeah but as per your assumed data i have given code like  this @manasasai

Comment: isnull(mart,0) is shorter

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have `Number` table contains series of Numbers without gaps. Try this

```
SELECT nr, 
       COALESCE(mart, 0) AS mart 
FROM   numbers n 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN mart m 
                    ON m.martid = n.nr 
WHERE  n.nr BETWEEN (SELECT Min(martid) 
                     FROM   mart) AND (SELECT Max(martid) 
                                       FROM   mart)
```

In case you don't have `numbers` table then refer this [***link***](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) to generate sequence of values in `SQL Server`. I will prefer `STACKED CTE` method

```
;WITH e1(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
), -- 10
e2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b), -- 10*10
e3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e2) -- 10*100
  SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) FROM e3 ORDER BY n;
```

Comment: can we achieve this in loop condition

Comment: why you want to use loop when there is a solution without loop which is efficient

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below if you just want to display the data:

```
SELECT 
    n.MartId, 
    ISNULL(m.mart, 0)
FROM 
    numbers n
    LEFT JOIN Mart m ON n.MartId = m.martID
ORDER BY
    n.MartId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using recursive cte,

```
DECLARE @Max_var INT=(SELECT Max(martid)
  FROM   Mart);

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT 1 AS Value
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Value=Value + 1
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  ( Value + 1 ) <= @Max_var)
SELECT Value,
       Isnull(mart, 0)
FROM   cte A
       LEFT JOIN Mart B
              ON A.Value = B.martID
```